# Bootstrap horizontal scrolling tabs in angular 8

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, angular8

I am using Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs functionality to create horizontal scrolling tabs in Angular 8.
Here is the Pen I am referring to [scrollTab](https://codepen.io/srees/pen/pgVLbm).

I tried everything but it does not seem to work for Angular 8.

Please help out.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroller scroller-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></div>
  <div class="scroller scroller-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs list" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab15</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab16</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tab17</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you're running that extra javascript from the codepen on your Angular application?
How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

First install angular 8

Expand node module (library root folder)

Go to the bootstrap folder and expand it.

Angular 8 Expand Root Folder
Go to dist folder and expand it.

Go to dist folder and expand it
Expand CSS, and we will find “bootstrap.css.” Expand bootstrap.css, and we will see bootstrap.min.css

Expand CSS
Open angular.js file and bootstrap.min.css in the style section.

Bootstrap is installed for your Angular 8 project. We can use it now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have set up my Angular 8 project and bootstrap 4 is working fine.

Comment: It's my pleasure 

Comment: Sometimes updated version may have problem you can try angular7 may that work